# JQuery hover stop().fadeIn() issue

Tags: html, jquery

I have a problem with the stop function when combined with fadeIn.

My fadeIn is set to 2000 ms, and I introduced the stop() so the animation doesn't build up. However, the problem is that when I use stop(true, true), it skips to the end of the animation. If I use just stop() the effect doesn't work 100% of the time when hovering the target multiple times. ie. if there are two div's with this effect next to each other, and I move the cursor over each really fast, the hover effect doesn't initiate.

Here is the code.

```
$('#menu li').hover(
//Mousein    
function() {
    $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
},

//Mouseout
function() {
    $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000);   

});
```

Is there a way to make the animation stop/start properly without making it skip to the end?

Comment: The second variable is "*jumpToEndA*: Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false." Have you tried "(true, false)"?

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify exactly what you mean by "doesn't work 100% of the time." However, if you are using a version of jQuery earlier that 1.7, you *might* be seeing this known defect:

> As of jQuery 1.7, stopping a toggled animation prematurely with .stop() will trigger jQuery's internal effects tracking. In previous versions, calling the .stop() method before a toggled animation was completed would cause the animation to lose track of its state (if jumpToEnd was false). Any subsequent animations would start at a new "half-way" state, sometimes resulting in the element disappearing.

See "Toggling Animations" at [.stop() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I cooked up. Not really a solution, just a conversation starter. Seems to work OK as long as the mouse is inside the window viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/mcritz/AwzQ7/